# Form not appearing using Django/HTML/Python

Tags: python, html, css, django, forms

I am new to Django and web development. I don't know how to describe my problem. No idea what info to provide. I need some hints to debug.

I have two virtual machines. On one machine, I built my Django project, installed the package, and run it on apache2. 
On the other machine, I run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` from the source codes.

Browsing the same page, the web page on machine 1 is OK. 
[image]

But nearly every form disappeared on machine 2. 
[image]

Checked the source of the two pages, they are the same. 
The output on machine 2 seems OK too:

```
[17/Mar/2016 19:36:40] "GET /myapp/dashboard/reports/new HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Mar/2016 19:36:40] "GET /myapp/dashboard/reports/0 HTTP/1.1" 200 43321
[17/Mar/2016 19:36:40] "GET /myapp/static/dist/css/vendor.css?v=v1.71 HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Mar/2016 19:36:40] "GET /myapp/static/css/main.css?v=v1.71 HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Mar/2016 19:36:40] "GET /myapp/static/css/dashboard.css?v=v1.71 HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Mar/2016 19:36:40] "GET /myapp/static/css/query.css?v=v1.71 HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Mar/2016 19:36:40] "GET /myapp/static/css/report.css?v=v1.71 HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Mar/2016 19:36:40] "GET /myapp/static/dist/js/commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71 HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Mar/2016 19:36:40] "GET /myapp/static/dist/js/analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71 HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

**UPDATE**
ERROR:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a functiont.exports.n.View.extend.initialize @ analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:2e.View @ commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:56n @ commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:56t.exports.n.View.extend.initialize @ analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:1e.View @ commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:56n @ commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:56(anonymous function) @ analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:1c @ commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:24h.fireWith @ commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:24vt.extend.ready @ commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:24h @ commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:14
```

**UPDATE**

Solved this problem. see the error above. It failed to import some js files, and then the page not shown.

Answer (score 1):

If they're each using separate copies of the database server, it may be that database migrations have not been run yet on machine 2.

Comment: I will double check.